# Get folder names using 2 datepicker(textbox) in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, textbox, datepicker

I have 2 textboxes turn into jquery datepickers and some folder names like `09-13-2014, 09-14-2014` and `09-15-2014`, how can I get all folder names from the selected dates on button click and place it on a treeview? I'm new to this, not yet familliar on the back end coding.

Here's my datepickers:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
          $("[id$=txtDate1]").datepicker({
              dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy', 
              showOn: 'button',
              buttonImageOnly: true,
              buttonImage: 'Images/calendar.png'
          });
      });
</script>

<p>
From: <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true"></asp:TextBox>
To:<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate2" runat="server" ReadOnly = "true"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" />
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I supposed that you datepicker working fine and it showing the calender.

```
   <p>
                From:
//you should delete ReadOnly = "true" on textboxes 
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                To:<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            </p>

            <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
            </asp:TreeView>
```

on code behinde write this codes. you can go to codebehind by rightclick on your page and then selecting view code.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var start = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate1.Text);
        var end = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate2.Text);

        if (end < start)
            return;

        var folderNamelst = GetListOfExsistingFolderName(start, end);
        AddNodes(folderNamelst);
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetListOfExsistingFolderName(DateTime startDate, DateTime endTime)
    {
        var mainFolderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Folders");
        var folderNamelst = new List<string>();
        var day = startDate;
        do
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(mainFolderPath + "\\" + day.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")))
                folderNamelst.Add(day.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"));
            day = day.AddDays(1);
        } while (day <= endTime);

        return folderNamelst;
    }

    private void AddNodes(IEnumerable<string> data)
    {
        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();

        var root = new TreeNode("Folders");

        foreach (var d in data)
        {
            var treechild = new TreeNode(d);
            root.ChildNodes.Add(treechild);
        }
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(root);
    }
```